# Unable to setup broker-bean for ActiveMQ

Tags: xml, osgi, activemq-classic, broker, springsource-dm-server

I've been having problems configuring an ActiveMQ broker through an xBean-parsed external XML file. At this point, ANY help, tips, pointers, hints or even cheering-up are appreciated. Here's my issue:

I'm trying to use an external .xml file to configure a broker. I have the following code in my spring bundle context:

```
<bean id="brokerFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.xbean.BrokerFactoryBean">  
 <property name="config" value="file:c:/activemq.xml" />  
 <property name="start" value="false" />  
</bean>
```

This should link with the configuration file with no further problems. Here is what my activemq.xml file looks like:

```
<beans 
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"/>

 <amq:broker useJmx="true" xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core">

    <networkConnectors>
      <!-- 
      <networkConnector uri="multicast://default?initialReconnectDelay=100" />
      <networkConnector uri="static://(tcp://localhost:61616)" />
       -->
    </networkConnectors>

    <persistenceFactory>
      <journalPersistenceAdapterFactory journalLogFiles="5" dataDirectory="${basedir}/target/foo" />

    </persistenceFactory>

    <transportConnectors>
      <transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:61636" />
    </transportConnectors>
  </amq:broker>
</beans>
```

As you can see it's a pretty standard one. When starting out my bundles I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name     'brokerManager' defined in URL [bundle://7.0:0/META-INF/spring/bundle-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'brokerFactory' while setting  bean property 'brokerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerFactory' defined in URL [bundle://7.0:0/META-INF/spring/bundle-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 10 in XML document from OSGi resource[file:c:/activemq.xml|bnd.id=7|bnd.sym=genericenqueuer-engine] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be  found for element 'amq:broker'.
```

I have tried several configurations for the namaspaces involved. Using the broker tags with and without the `"amq:"` declaration (`<broker>` and `<amq:broker>`) and specifying the specific version number for the activemq .xsd declaration. Still, the .xsd file doesn't seem to be found. If I provide the version number for the activemq .xsd file I get this instead:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerFactory' defined in URL [bundle://7.0:0/META-INF/spring/bundle-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unrecognized xbean namespace mapping: http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core
```

I am using xbean-spring version 3.7 which can be found [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xbean/xbean-spring). I have tried extracting the .xsd file from my `com.springsource.org.apache.activemq-5.3.0.jar` bundle file and exporting it on a package in one of my bundles but the parser still can't seem to find it. I have also posted a bug on the Geronimo [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GERONIMO-5522) for the issue.

Can anyone shed some light on the issue?

Thanks in advance,
Eduardo.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. The first is to expose your `brokerFactory` as an osgi service using the `<osgi:service ...>` tags and importing it in your second bundle where you reference the bean. The other option is to use your `brokerFactory` in the same bundle. Hope it helps...